# ¿cómo iniciar app al encender el celular?

Tags: java, android-studio

quiero que mi app se inicie cuando enciendo o reinicio mi celular, he probado con varios códigos que he encontrado, pero no he logrado que ninguno funcione.

Lo último que he usado es este código, lo he probado en android 10 y 12, pero igualmente no me funciona en ninguno.

Alguna sugerencia.

Gracias

Manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<receiver
        android:name=".Booteo"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:directBootAware="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.REBOOT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Booteo.java

```
public class Booteo extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Intent activityIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            activityIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(activityIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sugerencia: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42900345/15298643

Comment: Hola @javdromero gracias por tu sugerencia.  Ya he probado varias cosas de las que sugieren en ese link, pero sigue sin funcionar. Yo pienso que es algo de permisos que me falta

Comment: Hola @javdromero gracias, probe algo que había en el link que me enviaste y me funciono.